# Dictionary of keys where each has a specific value type

Tags: ios, swift

I want to define a dictionary where each key has a specific value type, like this:

```
let dictionary: [SomeEnumCase: SomeEnumCase.Value] = [
   .foo: "value",
   .bar: true
]
```

In this instance the keys always come from an enum. Each key has a specific value type. For example, `.foo` can only have a corresponding value of type `String`. Writing a `Bool` to `.foo` should throw a compile time error. How can I do this?

Comment: "Writing a Bool to .foo should throw an error" A compile time error or a runtime error?

Comment: @Sweeper Compile time

Comment: So what if I did `dictionary[Bool.random() ? .foo : .bar] = "value"`? Should that be an error or not? How do you figure that out at compile time? There is clearly a flaw in your design here. I think this might be a [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info). What do you intend on doing with the dictionary?

Comment: Maybe don't use a `Dictionary`, but a custom `struct` to do so, and if you really like the subcript, you can add it to your struct... Could you explain what you want to do with `dictionary`?

Comment: It looks like associated values for each of your enum cases would do what you need https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Enumerations.html

Comment: Thanks everyone, I am going to go for a custom struct instead

Answer (score 1):

dictionary isn't best choice for this functionality, use struct instead

```
struct EnumContainer {
   private var dictionary: [SomeEnumCase: Any] = [:]

   var foo: String? { dictionary[.foo] as? String }
   var bar: Bool? { dictionary[.bar] as? Bool }

   func setFoo(_ string: String) {
       dictionary[.foo] = string
   }
   func setBar(_ bool: Bool) {
       dictionary[.bar] = bool
   }
}
```